# How to stop/pause an python script embedded in c++

Tags: python, c++

I have a python script that constantly runs in the background and writes it's output to a file, I have initialized it using Python.h class in c++.
I want to read from the file when the user make an action, therefore i need to somehow pause or stop the python script.

I would like to know if there is a way of sending c++ pointers to the python function and stopping the script by changing the object in the c++ code.
Or maybe force the script to stop.
Thanks, Ori.

Comment: Why not split the script into stages and run stages 1..N first, pause, then run N+1 .. M later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can force the script to stop using this line of code
  `system("pkill -f name-of-the-python-script");` in the c++ program.
- You can also use the c++ program to write in another file and check it in every iteration in the python script. If
  it's empty continue, otherwise: `sys.exit()` but don't forget to `import sys`

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
For the first solution- I am on windows so pkill isn't an option.
For the second one- I will try it and see the result.